# Is it possible to automatically separate the code generated by STM32CubeIDE into headers and source files for each type of peripherals?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

When I create a new project in STM32CubeIDE with the use of a configuration (.ioc) file, configure peripherals, and generate code, all handlers (such as I2C_HandleTypeDef, UART_HandleTypeDef, QSPI_HandleTypeDef, DMA_HandleTypeDef, etc.) and their initialization functions are placed in main.c file.

Instead, is there a way to automatically split the code into multiple pairs of headers and source files (let's say, a header-source pair for UART, a header-source pair for I2C, etc.)?

I would like to define some custom parameters and functions related to my peripherals. Of course, I can create additional headers and source files. But I would prefer to group them all together without producing multiple files. It would simplify the maintenance of a code base.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

As one community member replied to me on [ST's forum](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D73W000001NDbK/detail?s1oid=00Db0000000YtG6&s1nid=0DB0X000000DYbd&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&s1uid=0053W000002RsPm&emtm=1641314774194&fromEmail=1&s1ext=0), to do so, one would need to open their project, .ioc file, go to Project Manager >>> Code Generator, and select "Generate peripheral initialization as a pair of '.c/.h' files per peripheral".